# De Morgan's laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

one can prove de Morgan's laws in set theory by induction. Are these laws true for an uncountable set of indices ( sets ) ?

Can somebody give a proof for one of the laws in the case of uncountable number of sets ? Is there any restriction on the cardinality of the sets on which these laws operate ?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Just show each set is a subset of the other. It's straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean transforming the sets without changing the final result ( for instance the union into a union of proper subsets each of which is included in the next term of the sequence ) ? But this will mean one still requires a sequence and thus cant go beyond the countability !

Comment: No. I meant argue as Asaf does in his answer in the liked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. If you translate set membership into logical statements, the infinite version boils down to "$\forall\neg=\neg\exists$".